# Jacobi field J along geodesic, satisfying additional condition $[J, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}] = 0.$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, geodesic

Following came up reading different articles and books:

Let $p$ be a point on a Riemannian manifold. For $x \in M \backslash Cut(p)$ let $\gamma$ be the minimal geodesic joining $p$ and $x$ parametrized by the distance, such that $\gamma(0) = p$, $\gamma(r) = x$.

Now let $X$ be a vector in $T_x M$ such that $\langle X, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \rangle$ (x) = 0. 
Since $x$ is not a conjugate point of $p$, we can extend $X$ to a Jacobi field $\tilde{X}$ along $\gamma$ satisfying $\tilde{X}(\gamma(0)) = 0, \tilde{X}(\gamma(r)) = X$ and $[\tilde{X}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}] = 0.$

My problem is the last part: Why does such a Jacobi field exist, that it commutes with $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$?

More particular: Don't the first two conditions already determine $\tilde{X}$ uniquely? If yes, how to see that the commutator vanishes? If not, how can one defind such a Jacobi field?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't say what $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ means -- I assume you mean it to be the unit radial vector field centered at $p$. Where did you see this? The expression $[\tilde X,\frac{\partial}{\partial r}]$ doesn't make any sense. The Lie bracket is only defined between vector fields defined on an open set; but $\tilde X$ is defined only along $\gamma$. Are you sure you didn't misread something?

Comment: @JackLee Thank you for your answer. This is more or less cited from "Lectures on Differential Geometry", by R. Schoen and S.-T. Yau.

Comment: ...Now as far as I have understood $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is as you say the unit radial vector field centered at p. Still I was thinking a bit more about $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, but I am not sure: It also coincides with the basis vector $\partial_n$, when I use polar coordinates $(\phi_0, r)$, with $\phi_0 \in S^n$. In this case using a unit speed geodesic (I assume "parametrized by distance" means parametrized by arc lenght), then $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ coincides with the velocity vector $\dot{\gamma}$ and also coincides with a coordinate basis vector in polar coordinates

Comment: I can also add another reference, but it is not stated out clearly (still I think he uses, that the let's say "kind of Lee bracket" vanishes). It can be found here: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/16S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec21.pdf on the first page at the bottom, and next page the definition of the Hessian. Somehow implicitly it is written in there, that the "kind-of commutator" vanishes (or am I wrong?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I looked at the reference you cited in your comment (Lectures on Differential Geometry by Schoen and Yau -- for anyone interested, this argument occurs on page 3). It turns out that they pulled a sneaky trick here, which they didn't explain very well.

Although they say "we can extend $X$ to a Jacobi field $\tilde X$ along $\sigma$," what they're actually doing is something more subtle. First they create a Jacobi field along $\sigma$ with the appropriate values at $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(r)$, which is possible because $\gamma(r)$ is inside the cut distance from $\gamma(0)$ and thus it's not a conjugate point to $\gamma(0)$.

But then, without saying so, they're also extending that Jacobi field to an actual vector field in a neighborhood of the image of $\sigma$, with the requirement that it commute with $\partial/\partial r$. That you can do so is not exactly a trivial observation, but it's well known to differential geometers. The simplest way to see this is to note that in geodesic polar coordinates $(r,\theta^1,\dots,\theta^{n-1})$ centered at $p$, the Jacobi fields along radial geodesics that vanish at $p$ and are orthogonal to $\partial/\partial r$ are exactly the vector fields of the form $J = a^1\partial/\partial \theta^1 + \dots + a^{n-1}\partial/\partial\theta^{n-1}$ where the coefficients $(a^1,\dots,a^{n-1})$ are ***constants***. Verifying this boils down to a couple of basic observations about normal coordinates: (1) The Gauss lemma shows that each vector field $\partial/\partial \theta^i$ is orthogonal to $\partial/\partial r$; (2) Each such vector field $J$ is the variation field of a variation through radial geodesics of the form $\gamma_s(t) = (t,sa^1,\dots,sa^{n-1})$ in polar coordinates, and therefore is a Jacobi field.

And finally, the fact that the extended vector field commutes with $\partial/\partial r$ follows immediately from the fact that the $a^i$'s are constants.

Comment: Thank you! What I still do not understand is, why J, if it is written in that form you mentioned, vanishes at $p$, if the coefficients $(a^1, \ldots, a^{n-1})$ are all constant.

Comment: Polar coordinates are not defined at $p$. To see what happens there, you have to convert back to standard geodesic normal coordinates.

Comment: Following your answer I think I have finally understood now: First step: Having both conditions $J(0) = 0$ and $J(r) = X$, where $X \in T_x M$ defines a Jacobi field along $\gamma$ uniquely (but not a vector field in a neighborhood of $\gamma$, so that $[J(t), \frac{\partial}{\partial r}] = 0$ makes not really sense).

Comment: ...Then afterwards (!) the extension $V$ of $J$ to the neighborhood is done in polar coordinates. As you already explained the Jacobi field $J$ along $\gamma$ in polar coordinates is then given by $J = a^1 \partial/\partial \theta^1 + \ldots + a^{n-1} \partial/\partial \theta^{n-1}$, which is then orthogonal AND constant in relation to $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, which shows, that the Lie-bracket $[V, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}]$ in this particular chosen coordinate system vanishes. 
The steps you explained helped to see that $J$ is indeed a Jacobi-field. Can you confirm?

Comment: @VolkerE. : Yes, that’s right.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank you kindly.